# In Microsoft Edge, Vue does a web page error! It works well in other browsers. What’s the problem?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, microsoft-edge

my vue version : 2.1.10

[Vue warn]:

> Error in render: "TypeError: Unable to get property 'Product' of undefined or null reference"

(found in Root>

[image]

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'Product' of undefined or null reference

[Vue warn]:

> Property or method "*this*" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in Root>)

[Vue warn]:

> Error in render: "TypeError: Unable to get property 'order_id' of undefined or null reference"

(found in Root>)

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'order_id' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Try to provide a sample code and detailed steps to produce the issue. With only error message we cannot decide what's the actual issue and whether it is related with MS Edge or Vue.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem. In my case, this was due to the fact that I was referring to the object inside inline-template component through `this`.

**Example:**

*my-details.js*

```
export default Vue.component('myDetails', {
  data() {
   forms: {...},
   countryCodes: {
     1: '7',
     2: '380',
     3: '375',
     4: '77',
     5: '994',
     6: '374',
     7: '995',
     8: '972',
     9: '1',
     10: '1',
     11: '996'
   },
  }
});
```

*index.php*

```
<section class="my-details h-base-type" inline-template is="myDetails">
  ...
  <div v-if="codeValid || countryCodes[this.forms.company.country_id] !== '7'">...</div>
  ...
</section>
```

After I fixed it, the error disappeared

*index.php*

```
  ...
  <div v-if="codeValid || countryCodes[forms.company.country_id] !== '7'">...</div>
  ...
```

Check the template document on `this`.

Comment: If the error keeps appearing in the console after your removed all `this` you could find, close edge and open it again.